# NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise

I am using rails testing for my app and when I run this test

```
class ShowingQuizzesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    include Devise::TestHelpers
    setup { host! 'example.com' }
    test 'return quiz by id' do 
        instructor=Instructor.create(name:"same7", email:"abcdefg@eng.asu.edu.com", password:"123abc")
        sign_in instructor
        quiz = Quiz.create(name: 'Quiz1', subject: 'physics', duration: 10, no_of_MCQ: 5, no_of_rearrangeQ: 5) 
        current_instructor.quizzes << quiz
        get "api/quizzes/#{quiz.id}"
        assert_equal 200, response.status

        quiz_response = json(response.body)
        assert_equal quiz.name, quiz_response[:name]
    end
end
```

This error appears:
1) Error:
ShowingQuizzesTest#test_return_quiz_by_id:
NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass

the method I am testing:

```
   def show
            current_instructor.quizzes.find(params[:id])
            render json: data:{:quiz => quiz}, status: 200
        end
```

Comment: Can you also post the method that you're testing

Comment: def create
//quiz = Quiz.new(quiz_params)
   //if quiz.save
    //current_instructor.quizzes << quiz
    //render json: { success: true, data:{:quiz => quiz}, info:{} }, status: 201
   //else
    //render json: { success: false, data:{}, :info => quiz.errors }, status: 422
   //end
  //end
  //private
  //def quiz_params
   //params.require(:quiz).permit(:name, :subject, :duration, :no_of_MCQ, :no_of_rearrangeQ)
  //end

Comment: @Finks take a look again at the question I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Rails 5?

It looks like Rails 5 deprecated the old method of including test helpers - as the Rails team has made significant improvements to the speed of integration tests.  Currently, all controllers are tested in integration tests - [Link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/issues/695)

I'm getting the same error when dealing with devise & testing.  I was able to make the error go away by commenting out `# include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` from my test file or the `test_helpers.rb` if you inherit your test helpers there.